# Trying to test getters method using Vuex & Vue

Tags: vue.js, getter, vuex

I am new to Vuex and I am trying a simple test using a getter to return a data property from the state. I'm attempting to display the returned data on the page.

COMPONENT.VUE

```
    <template>
      <div class="section" > 
        <div class="section-content"> 
          <p>{{test.title}}</p>                               
        </div>                                                         
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'startNewSearch',
      computed: {
        getTest() { return this.$store.getters.getTest }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

GETTERS.JS

```
    export default {
        getTest(state) {
            return state.test
        }
    }
```

STORE.JS

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

    import actions from './actions'
    import mutations from './mutations'
    import getters from './getters'

    Vue.use(Vuex);

    export const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            newSearch: {},
            test: {
                title: 'Test',
                msg: 'This is a test message'
            }
        },
        getters,
        mutations,
        actions
    })
```

The error that I get is that test is- Property or method "test" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Is there another step to saving the data to the component that I missed?

Comment: change the computed property  `getTest` to just `test`

Comment: I figured it would be something simple! Thanks Eric

Comment: Have a look at my article to see how to mock vuex in tests - https://www.coding123.org/mock-vuex-in-vue-unit-tests/